# Spring cache support requires ApplicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm running into an issue trying to use Spring caching with ehcache in my application. For reasons that I can't elaborate on, my application uses a graph of BeanFactories instead of ApplicationContexts. This approach has worked well as long as we manually register our BeanPostProcessors, as is called out in the Spring documentation.

We are now adding caching to the app. When we used the simplest annotation configuration, it works.

// This works

```
package com.x.y.z;

public class RoleManager {
    private String user;

    public RoleManager( String user ) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return user;
    }

    @Cacheable("user")
    public boolean isAllowed(String permissionId, Map<String,?> params)
    {
        ... lengthy and expensive operation to determine if user is permitted to do something
    }
}
```

We configure this to using spring xml for this bean factory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation=
       "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd"> 

    <cache:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="roleManager" class="com.x.y.z.RoleManager" scope="prototype"/>
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcacheManager"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="ehcacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="file:${conf.dir}/ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
... unrelated business beans elided ...
```

We are using Spring 4.1.9 and ehcache 2.10.2

The above code works quite well. Our ehcache instance for "user" begins to fill as we get cache misses, and returns cached values for hits.

Once this was running correctly, we found that it isn't possible to evict all the entries for a particular user because the cache key is a concatenation of the permissionid and the Map::toString result. We decided to create a cache per user so we would have more control over eviction. To use Spring, we need to use a CacheResolver to accomplish this.

```
package com.x.y.z;

import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheResolver;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheOperationInvocationContext;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class MyCacheResolver extends AbstractCacheResolver {
    public MyCacheResolver() {
    }

    public MyCacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        super(cacheManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected Collection<String> getCacheNames(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> cacheOperationInvocationContext) {
        if(cacheOperationInvocationContext.getTarget() instanceof RoleManager) {
            return Collections.singleton(((RoleManager) cacheOperationInvocationContext.getTarget()).getName());
        }
        return Collections.singleton("user");
    }
}
```

We wire this up by adding a new bean definition

```
<bean id="myCacheResolver" class="com.x.y.z.MyCacheResolver">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="cacheManager"/>
</bean>
```

And change the annotation in RoleManager to

```
@Cacheable(cacheResolver="myCacheResolver")
```

Once we do this, however, we get the following exception when the isAllowed method is invoked:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getBean(CacheAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getCacheOperationMetadata(CacheAspectSupport.java:254)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.getOperationContext(CacheAspectSupport.java:226)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport$CacheOperationContexts.<init>(CacheAspectSupport.java:500)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.isAllowed(Unknown Source)
    at com.x.y.z.RoleManager.isAllowed(CompositeRoleManager.java:61)
```

When I look at the CacheAspectSupport class from the stack trace, I see that it has a member, applicationContext, which is null.

```
protected <T> T getBean(String beanName, Class<T> expectedType) {
        return BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(this.applicationContext, expectedType, beanName);
    }
```

This seems like a bug in Spring to me since we do not use ApplicationContexts, and yet caching works until we need to use a CacheResolver. I've looked over the documentation and I see no mention that one must use ApplicationContexts in order to use the Spring caching abstraction.

I guess my question is, has anyone experienced this problem, and if so, what did you do to resolve it? We absolutely cannot use ApplicationContexts in our application, and I'd rather not throw out a perfectly usable abstraction and code directly to the ehcache (or JSR-107) APIs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems that Spring 4.3 added a setBeanFactory() method to CacheAspectSupport class, and deprecated the setApplicationContext() method. I wasn't able to find an issue in their JIRA corresponding to the change, but I did verify that my code works with Spring 4.3

Answer (score 1):

Spring 4.3 has fixed the problem by adding a setBeanFactory() method and using the BeanFactory thus set to call the CacheResolvers. Unfortunately I am unable to update our Spring library code to 4.3 at this time, but it will work when we are able to upgrade in the future.